# Delete a line of text in txt file iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Is it possible to delete a line of text that store in .txt file. I am currently successful to extract each line inside txt file and add into array then display each line in TableView. Now I if I want to delete particular line How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the strings from your `NSArray` into a `NSMutableArray`, delete the line that you want deleted, convert to a single `NSString` by joining elements with `@"\n"` string, and then write the string to file, like this:

```
NSMutableArray *tmp = [myArray mutableCopy];
[tmp removeObjectAtIndex:indexToRemove];
NSString *tmpStr = [NSString componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
NSError *err = nil;
[tmpStr writeToFile:myFile
         atomically:NO
           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding  // <== use an encoding that you need
              error:&err];
```

Comment: thank you for replay the result is that it actually save but it save all structure into txt file example below:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
 <string>011.smil#txt139</string>
 <string>011.smil#txt139</string>
 <string>006.smil#txt59</string>
 <string>011.smil#txt139</string>
</array>
</plist>
But I want only content inside strings tag